# Modify subscription product listing in my-account - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce subscription but i am facing some issue in customization i want add product image and replace subscription id.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNiAk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function add_image_to_subscription_list( $subscription ) {

    foreach ( $subscription->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        $_product  = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_order_item_product', $subscription->get_product_from_item( $item ), $item );

        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {


            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(  $item['product_id'] ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

            echo "<img src=".$image[0]." data-id=".$item['product_id'].">";

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_my_subscriptions_after_subscription_id', 'add_image_to_subscription_list', 35 );
```